# Inkscape Rubber Stamp Tutorial: Is this for real?

Tags: inkscape, tutorial

I was trying to work myself through a few tutorials today, but I have noticed something odd:

[Here's a nice rubber stamp effect tutorial](http://howto.nicubunu.ro/rubber_stamp_inkscape/) with two circles and text.  [image]

The tutorial's text instructs you to cover the "stamp" with the `calligraphic tool` like the images shows and then apply `Intersection` to the paths. The result should look like indicated, only chips and chunks should be removed from the original stamp. But wait a minute, if you would apply intersection to the stamp which is almost covered with the calligraphic tool's ink, wouldn't that remove almost everything if you apply `Intersection`? Am I missing something or tutorials just don't seem to be legit these days?

UPDATE:

I kind of figured out something, applying `Intersection` is right, but I have some problems when the tutorial says convert the circles and the text to path. After that no path operations seem to work. If I just leave the circles and the text without converting them to paths, the effects do apply.

UPDATE 2:

OK, there was actually nothing particularly wrong with the tutorial I linked to in the description, you just need to know about `Ungrouping` [Ctrl] + [U] which comes in handy when you want to create a `Union`. :)

Comment: Using a random form and the spray tool to cover the original image should work too, maybe faster than using the calligraphic tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing `Path>Difference` with `Path>Intersection`. The tutorial is correct, that's what you would get as your output.

Comment: Yes, I have just understood that, but I still have a problem with converting everything to paths. In that case none of the path operations seems to take effect, if I do not convert to paths, it seems to work.

Comment: It looks pretty good to me. Did you expand the circles' strokes and do a `Union` operation on the text and outlines?

Comment: First I selected the text and did `Path > Object  to Path`, then click one of the circles, `Stroke to Path` and then did the same for the other circle. Finally I selected everything and did `Path > Union`. After covering the "stamp" with some calligraphic ink, I tried applying `Intersection`, but nothing happened.

Comment: OK, I think I have figured out. I need to make sure that **everything** really gets selected. If the "stamp" is almost covered in ink and I pull the selection tool over the whole thing, it doesn't mean everything is selected. Damnn.... Also, `Ungrouping` is required to get the `Union` work. Nice to know :)